# Xcode 5 Debug - "Unnamed" Thread in CPU Report / Usage

Tags: ios, xcode, multithreading, macos, cpu

XCode 5 present CPU usage report, including processing break up of each running thread. That's good and helpful to some extent.

**But, can we give these threads programmatically some names so that it's easy to identify them?** These threads are spawned by OS when my app schedule few NSTimers, NSOperation, NSURLConnection etc but I can't exactly map or identify threads shown in CPU report with their respective operations.

As you can see in the screenshot below, most of these threads are "Unnamed" making it difficult to identify the associated operations.

[image]

Also, in general, what is the best way to comprehend this CPU report? Any suggestions please.

Comment: NSOperationQueue and NSThread have `name` property and you can pass a name to `dispatch_queue_create` function, did you try them?

Comment: Based on your suggestion I gave one of `NSOperationQueue` a self.operationQueue.name = @"My Operation Queue" using name property but i think since each `NSOperation` is executed by spawning a new `NSThread` implicitly/internally so this `name` didn't show up in CPU report. Also, I don't create `NSThread` directly for NSTimers etc so I don't know how could I set it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this tiny class to mark threads I need to identify in CPU monitor:
https://github.com/deszip/APThreadMarker

Just call:

```
[APThreadMarker markCurrentThreadWithName:@"thread 1"];
```

inside start method of your NSOperation subclass and thread created for this NSOperation will have provided name.